# ckeditor5 MentionCustomization Cannot read property 'createAttributeElement' of undefined

Tags: ckeditor5

I have (almost) successfully followed this tutorial https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html. After downloading a custom build of CKEditor5 with the Mention plugin from https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ I successfully got mention auto complete working (almost).

Problem: When trying to customize the mention output (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html#customizing-the-output) I get the error *Cannot read property 'createAttributeElement' of undefined* when the downcast function runs. The undefined object in question is the writer being passed into the view.

Can anyone suggest where to go from here. I have drawn a blank after many hours. Everything else is working - just not this customization function. I have copied the code exactly from the example given.

[image]

```
  editorConfig = {
    extraPlugins: [MentionLinks],
    placeholder: 'Start typing your notes here.',
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells',
            'tableCellProperties',
            'tableProperties'
        ]
    },
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageStyle:full', 'imageStyle: side', 'imageStyle:alignLeft', 'imageStyle:alignCenter', 'imageStyle:alignRight',
            '|',
            'imageResize',
            '|',
            'imageTextAlternative',
            '|',
            'linkImage'
        ],
        styles: [
            'full',
            'side',
            'alignLeft',
            'alignCenter',
            'alignRight'
        ],
        resizeOptions: [
            {
                name: 'imageResize:original',
                label: 'Original',
                value: null
            },
            {
                name: 'imageResize:50',
                label: '50%',
                value: '50'
            },
            {
                name: 'imageResize:75',
                label: '75%',
                value: '75'
            }
        ]
    },
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'undo',
            'redo',
            'heading',
            '|',
            'fontFamily',
            'fontSize',
            'fontBackgroundColor',
            'fontColor',
            'highlight',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            '|',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'todoList',
            '|',
            'indent',
            'outdent',
            'alignment',
            //'|',
            //'horizontalLine',
            //'pageBreak',
            //'|',
            'imageUpload',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            '|',
            'link',
            //'superscript',
            //'subscript',
            //'|',
            'mediaEmbed',
            //'|',
            'exportPdf'
        ]
    },
    mention: {
        feeds: [
            {
                marker: '@',
                feed: this.feedUsers,
              //  itemRenderer: this.customItemRenderer
            },
            {
                marker: '#',
                feed: getFeedItems
            }
        ]
    }
};

            /*
         * This plugin customizes the way mentions are handled in the editor model and data.
         * Instead of a classic <span class="mention"></span>,
         */
        function MentionLinks( editor ) {
            // The upcast converter will convert a view
            //
            //      <a href="..." class="mention" data-mention="...">...</a>
            //
            // element to the model "mention" text attribute.
            editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToAttribute( {
                view: {
                    name: 'a',
                    key: 'data-mention',
                    classes: 'mention',
                    attributes: {
                        href: true
                    }
                },
                model: {
                    key: 'mention',
                    value: viewItem => editor.plugins.get( 'Mention' ).toMentionAttribute( viewItem )
                },
                converterPriority: 'high'
            } );

            // Downcast the model "mention" text attribute to a view
            //
            //      <a href="..." class="mention" data-mention="...">...</a>
            //
            // element.
            editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).attributeToElement( {
                model: 'mention',
                view: ( modelAttributeValue, { writer } ) => {
                
                
                    debugger;
                
                    // Do not convert empty attributes (lack of value means no mention).
                    if ( !modelAttributeValue ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    let href;

                    // User mentions are downcasted as mailto: links. Tags become normal URLs.
                    if ( modelAttributeValue.id[ 0 ] === '@' ) {
                        href = `mailto:${ modelAttributeValue.id.slice( 1 ) }@example.com`;
                    } else {
                        href = `https://example.com/social/${ modelAttributeValue.id.slice( 1 ) }`;
                    }

                    return writer.createAttributeElement( 'a', {
                        class: 'mention',
                        'data-mention': modelAttributeValue.id,
                        href
                    }, {
                        // Make mention attribute to be wrapped by other attribute elements.
                        priority: 20,
                        // Prevent merging mentions together.
                        id: modelAttributeValue.uid
                    } );
                    
                    
                },
                converterPriority: 'high'
            } );
        }
```

Comment: Glad to see someone else having having the exact same problem I am now, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you come to a solution?

Comment: having same issue, did you found anything on it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I faced was actually what you described but in reverse.

The documentation was updated, however I did miss this change when upgrading from a lower version. Wasn't an issue in version 21, but started noticing it in version 27.1.

Updated documentation: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html

Basically, today, it seems you need to deconstruct the second parameter of the view function of the `for('downcast').attributeToElement` function.

Instead of `view: (modelAttributeValue, writer)`  it should be `view: (modelAttributeValue, { writer })`

My full code snippet for downcast:

```
editor.conversion.for('downcast').attributeToElement({
model: 'mention',
view: (modelAttributeValue: any, { writer }: any) => {
  if (!modelAttributeValue) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return writer.createAttributeElement(
    'span',
    {
      class: 'mention',
      'data-field-id': modelAttributeValue.fieldId,
    },
    {
      // Make mention attribute to be wrapped by other attribute elements.
      priority: 20,
      // Prevent merging mentions together.
      id: modelAttributeValue.uid,
    },
  );
},
converterPriority: 'high', });
```

But in your scenario, it might have been an older version. You could try removing the deconstruct. Hopefully this might help other people facing the original post's issue, or mine.